# Displaying array data in Angular html page using *ngFor

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

I"m calling an API that's returning the data as an object. I converted the object into an array which seems to be an multidimensional array. I can see the data in the console, but when I use *ngFor to display it in my form it will not show. I have tried placing the returned data in an array titled plans. in my ngFor I've tried plans.averagedefferalrate, plans.planid, etc.; plans.rankedWebPlans.averagdefferalrate, plans.rankedWebPlans.planid, etc. but can't seem to get the data to display. The code of this is also included. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

[image: Form in browser]

[image: Angular HTML Code]

[image: Angular Typescript Code]

Comment: Have you tried `let plan of plans.rankedWebPlans`?

Comment: Try `<p>Average Defferal Rate: {{plan?.planid}}</p>`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Unfortunately neither of the above solutions worked. It's still not displaying the values from the array.